# Python error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split, attributeerror

```
    if x=="recibidos":
        whatsintro_gui.borrar_lista_mensajes()
        nr=whatsintro_msg.cantidad_recibidos()
        k=0
        while k<=nr:
            recibido=whatsintro_msg.mensaje_recibido(k)
            [de,para,msg]=recibido.split(sep="\n", maxsplit=2)
            msg=desencriptar(msg)
            whatsintro_gui.agregar_mensaje_al_final(de,usuario,msg)
            k+=1

    if x=="enviados":
        whatsintro_gui.borrar_lista_mensajes()
        ne=whatsintro_msg.cantidad_recibidos()
        k=0
        while k<=ne:
            enviado=whatsintro_msg.mensaje_enviado(k)
            [de,para,msg]=enviado.split(sep="\n", maxsplit=2)
            msg=desencriptar(msg)
            whatsintro_gui.agregar_mensaje_al_final(usuario,para,msg)
            k+=1
```

When i run my program i get an error with both split methods used above. The error displayed is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'. i believe i am making a small error but i dont know, just starting programing.

thanks in advance

Ps: sorry for bad english

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: `whatsintro_msg.mensaje_enviado(k)` and the other method are probably returning `None`. You should look into why that would happen. Consider using `pdb`.

Answer (score 0):

That means one of your variables, either `enviado` or `recibido` is being set to None.  Do you expect some cases to return None?  If so, you can skip the split call on those cases:

```
        enviado=whatsintro_msg.mensaje_enviado(k)
        if enviado is not None:
            [de,para,msg]=enviado.split(sep="\n", maxsplit=2)
            msg=desencriptar(msg)
            whatsintro_gui.agregar_mensaje_al_final(usuario,para,msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at which line the traceback is pointing to - or paste it in the question if you can't understand it.

Possibly you forgot a return statement on one of the methods. That means the method will return `None` which doesn't have a `split` method